# REST API post give html response

Tags: java, spring, rest, security

I have a problem with REST API, when I make a request (POST) from my login form, I receive my signin html instead of User JSON. I guess problem is with configuration of Spring Security but I have no idea how to solve it.My configure method:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/signin.html","/index.css","/javascript/**", "api/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/signin.html");

}
```

and Post controller:

```
@PostMapping("")
public ResponseEntity<Object> save( @RequestBody @Valid UserDto user, BindingResult result){
    if(user.getId() != null)
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "User cannot be saved");
    System.out.println(result);
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        List<ObjectError> errors = result.getAllErrors();
        errors.forEach(err -> System.out.println(err.getDefaultMessage()));
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errors);
    }
    UserDto savedUser = userService.save(user);
    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
            .fromCurrentRequest()
            .path("{id}")
            .buildAndExpand(savedUser.getId())
            .toUri();
    return ResponseEntity.created(location).body(savedUser);
}
```

Request is made for /api/users. Can someone help?

Comment: Just a question : for every matchers in your antMatchers your start by / except for your api. Did you try with '/api/**' instead of 'api/**' ?

Comment: @Sodala yeah, it works the same.

Comment: Yes, you guessed it right. Problem is with "configuration of Spring Security"  So pls add your Spring Security code as well. It will help

Comment: The problem was with csrf. Already solved, thanks!